# How to detect if in the current buffer some text is selected (marked)?

Tags: mark

How to determine if in the current buffer some text is selected?

Comment: region-active-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `region-active-p`.

Just to add something to the short answer, `region-active-p` won't
work in `-batch`, so you need to enable this (which is actually
default in plain Emacs):

```
(transient-mark-mode 1)
```